# Zend Framework - How to place a text right to the text box?

Tags: zend-framework

How to place a text right to the text box in `Zend Framework`? I am using `Zend_Form` component in my project. I want to display a small text right side of text box. For example I want to display an example phone Number to the right side of the phone number text box field. How can I do this?
Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Use element's `description`

```
$element = $this->createElement('text', 'phone')
                ->setLabel('Phone Number:')
                ->setDescription('ex: 123-456-7890');
$this->addElement($element);
```